# avoid closing the menu if submenu items is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

This is a multilevel menu. When i click the link "About" it opens the submenu which contains 3 links Johnny, Julie & Jamie.

When i click "About" again, it closes the menu. Clicking the submenu also closes the menu, and that i want to avoid.

How do i avoid closing the opened submenu, if i click the submenu (Johnny, Julie & Jamie) ?

```js
$('li.parent').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Johnny</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Julie</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Jamie</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">AnotherLink
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Martin</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Rasmus</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Morten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative to [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) approach for child elements would be adding a small check if the clicked element is the current one (and not it's descendants):

```
$('li.parent').click(function(e) {
  if (this === e.target)
    $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```js
$('li.parent').click(function(e) {
  if (this === e.target)
    $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#nav ul.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="parent">About
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Johnny</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Julie</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Jamie</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">AnotherLink
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Martin</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Rasmus</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Morten</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like it. I think `if (e.target !== this) return;` might be even clearer (in case the event handler has more than one instruction)

Comment: @oliverpool Yeah, this makes perfect sense, especially when you have lots of things to do for the clicked element.

Comment: And btw, an anchor tag can contains other elements so would be better imho: `if ($(e.target).closest('.sub-nav').length) return;`

Comment: @A.Wolff This solution will be tooooooooo slow.

Comment: Its fine for me. Thanks for the help @VisioN.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes. On every click `.closest()` method will go up the DOM tree, check if the element matches the given selector and create new jQuery collection for checking its `length`. In the given answer `this === e.target` will evaluate instantly.

Comment: @VisioN Ya that's correct but there is nothing any user would notice it, i mean, we are speaking about nanoseconds regarding a click event. But your answer anyway seems more accurate in this case, so... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Well, probably milliseconds to be precise `:D` But yes, there are several ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @VisioN Ya, milliseconds seems more relevant, you beat me on this too :)

Comment: @VisioN, its not working for me: 
$('li.treeview').click(function(e) {
    if (this === e.target)
        $(this).find('.treeview-menu').toggleClass('visible');
});

<style>
#nav ul.treeview-menu {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}
</style>

Structure:
<ul id="nav">
 <li class="treeview">
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

Answer (score 3):

You need to `stopPropagation` of event on child anchor elements:

```
$("li.parent a").click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the click on the `.sub-nav` element to be transmitted to your event handler: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/